# why use 3rd party jaxrs libraries in a spring-mvc app(3.0/4/0)?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, cxf, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

This was an interview question and I didn't have a clear answer/idea myself.
The actual question was about **why mix up jersey and spring-mvc?**
I'm going one step ahead and asking is there no case for using **jersey/cxf** anymore with the latest versions of spring-mvc?

I'm hoping that this doesn't get pulled down for being an opinionated question.
It would be helpful if somebody here can shed more light about,
Is there no case now for jersey/cxf with spring especially if you are on spring 3.x/4.x.
Is there still a justification for going with jersey/cxf on a spring mvc app despite added support to restful services in the latest spring versions?

What is the thought process behind arriving at a particular combo?Is there anything other than familiarity?